What is wrong with this API call parsing JSON data?
This is the current SWIFTUI code I have:
import SwiftUI

struct Holidays: Decodable {
    var date: String
    var localName: String
    var name: String
    var countryCode: String
}

struct HolidaysView: View {
    @State private var holidays = [Holidays]()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(holidays, id: \.name) { t in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(t.date)
                        .font(.headline)
                        .foregroundColor(.cyan)
                    Text(t.name)
                        .font(.body)
                        .foregroundColor(.indigo)
                    Text(t.countryCode)
                        .font(.body)
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Holidays List")
            .task {
                await fetchHolidaysData()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func fetchHolidaysData() async {
        // create the URL
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://date.nager.at/api/v2/publicholidays/2020/US") else {
            print("THIS URL DOES NOT WORK!")
            return
        }
        
        // fetch the data
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            
            // decode that data
            if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Holidays].self, from: data) {
                holidays = decodedResponse
            }
        } catch {
            print("This data is not valid")
        }
    }
}

struct HolidaysView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HolidaysView()
    }
}


The goal of this code is to be able to view the json data using the URL.
When I click the navigation title of Holiday List, no data shows up (in contentview).
I have tried other API links such as API placeholders for JSON, and they worked. I can't figure out the issue or the difference. I tried AI as well. I do not know what I'm doing wrong, Could it possibly be that I have to use all the variables of data of the API? Or possibly the id? The other apis I used had ids for each section of data so I put
List(holidays, id: \.name) { t in      ```
as 

List(todos, id: \.id) { t in      ```
```, could this be a possible reason?
                       


Is print("This data is not valid") called? Is holidays = decodedResponse called? You should replace if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder() with let decodedResponse = try JSONDecoder()... and in the catch print("This data is not valid") -> print("This data is not valid: \(error)"). Currently, if there is an error in the decoding, you are just silencing it (with try?, the question mark being the silencer), and with your print, you're are ignoring the error caught, which could tell you why it failed.

your code with @Larme try suggestion, works well for me.
Note for the List to work you need to ensure the elements are unique.
To do that I recommend making your Holidays Identifiable, such as
struct Holidays: Identifiable, Decodable { let id = UUID()...
Then you can use List(holidays) ...

@workingdogsupportUkraine and Larme, thank you both so much, this really helped me!

Here is my working example code that brings together the comment's recommendations. The code lets you achieve your goal, as described The goal of this code is to be able to view the json data using the URL
struct Holidays: Identifiable, Decodable { // <-- here
    let id = UUID() // <-- here
    
    var date: String
    var localName: String
    var name: String
    var countryCode: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case date, localName, name, countryCode  // <-- here no id
    }
}

// for testing
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HolidaysView()
    }
}

struct HolidaysView: View {
    @State private var holidays = [Holidays]()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {  // <-- here
            List(holidays) { t in   // <-- here
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(t.date)
                        .font(.headline)
                        .foregroundColor(.cyan)
                    Text(t.name)
                        .font(.body)
                        .foregroundColor(.indigo)
                    Text(t.countryCode)
                        .font(.body)
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Holidays List")
            .task {
                await fetchHolidaysData()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func fetchHolidaysData() async {
        // create the URL
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://date.nager.at/api/v2/publicholidays/2020/US") else {
            print("THIS URL DOES NOT WORK!")
            return
        }
        // fetch the data
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            // decode that data
            holidays = try JSONDecoder().decode([Holidays].self, from: data) // <-- here
        } catch {
            print("error: \(error)") // <-- here, important
        }
    }
}

